# Сортировка постов wordpress по лайкам из соц. сетей

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеются 2 кнопки - с фейсбука и вконтакте, нужно сложить одно с другим и вывести в одно значение(вот хотя бы с этим прошу помощи), а дальше как я понял можно это значение поместить в кастомное поле и через него сортировать новости.

```
<div id="vk_like"><script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "mini"});
</script></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="/" data-layout="button_count" data action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-size="small" data-width="50" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Какое отношение это иеет к WP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Получить количество лайков из фейсбука:

   http://graph.facebook.com/?id={URL}
2. Получить количество лайков из контакта:

   http://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url={URL}
3. Сложить числа

**{URL}** - страница, счетчик которой нужно получить.